# Swift CGVector Inconsistencies

Tags: ios, swift, vector, sprite-kit

I am working on a SpriteKit game in which a sprite is thrown from the upper right portion of the screen and lands in about the middle. In order to propel the sprite, I am using the `applyForce` method. Currently, I am explicitly setting the values of the dx and dy of the vector.

Frequently, the sprite lands where I expect it to based on set dx and dy values. However, sometimes the sprite travels farther than intended.

Essentially the issue is that the sprite travels inconsistent distances when applied the same force vector. I am wondering if there is any way to counter this issue and maintain consistent results with the same applied vector.

Comment: The title makes no sense, CGVector is a struct with two properties, that cannot be “inconsistent.” If you have problems with concrete code then you should show that code, together with expected and actual results.

Comment: Your issue is not CGVector, but how Physics works.  The reason why you are getting inconsistent results has to do with how the framework handles each update frame.  It is not a static 60FPS, each update frame is different in terms of time.  Check to make sure your delta time is staying close to the 1/60 mark.  Any spike will cause unexpected results.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon that helped a lot thank you. I have an older mac so its graphical capabilities are somewhat limited. The issue only occurs on my computer while using the iOS simulator (running at about 35 frames with a delta of 4 or more), whereas my iPhone is able to hold 60 frames with no variation in behavior.